# Html.BeginForm will not return to POST actionresult - RAZOR

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a view to input results and feed back to the controller where I can save them to a database however when I click submit, my returns me to the GET actionresult instead, I have tried putting the BeginForm inside the  and it does work however it completely changes the display in my view by cramming all the input text boxes beside eachother. How can I keep my existing layout and submit to the POST actionresult?`

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateLecturer";
}

<br /><br /><br /><br />
<form class="form-horizontal">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateLecturer", "Admin", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Add Lecturer</legend>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="addLect" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Lecturer Number</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLect" name="addLect" placeholder="Lecturer Number">
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <label for="addLectFname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLectFname" name="addLectFname" placeholder="Firstname">
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <label for="addLectSname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Surname</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLectSname" name="addLectSname" placeholder="Surname">
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <label for="addLectPword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="addLectPword" name="addLectPword" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
         @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "ViewLecturer", "Admin", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
      
  </fieldset>
   }
 </form>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two forms now.. you can't use `<form>` and `Html.BeginForm` together. you need to use one or the other.

Try

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateLecturer", "Admin", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Lecturer</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addLect" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Lecturer Number</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLect" name="addLect" placeholder="Lecturer Number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addLectFname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLectFname" name="addLectFname" placeholder="Firstname">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addLectSname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Surname</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLectSname" name="addLectSname" placeholder="Surname">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addLectPword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="addLectPword" name="addLectPword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "ViewLecturer", "Admin", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Your other option is to remove the `@using BeginForm` and just use

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="@Url.Action("CreateLecturer","Admin")" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

</form>
```